# Dividir variable factor en R

Tags: r, csv

mi problema es el siguiente:

a través de una webform (en mi caso alojado en la plataforma ONA) recojo datos de una determinada población de estudio. El formato de recogida de datos lo he diseñado usando XLSForms y hay muchas preguntas multi-respuestas (adjunto abajo un ejemplo a través de ENKETO):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando exporto los datos recogidos como un fichero csv, si hago que cada opción sea una columna (una variable por tanto con valor true o false), al ser la encuesta muy larga, el número de variables resulta excesivamente alto y el fichero generado se hace poco manejable, por lo que exporto los datos de forma que cada pregunta es una variable y los valores son todas las respuestas marcadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación todo mi análisis lo pretendo hacer con R:

```
tabla <- read.csv("prueba.csv")
str(tabla)
```

> $ sign_trauma                               : Factor w/ 6 levels
>   "Flashbacks Avoidance Nightmares/Night_Terror",..: 1 2 6 3 5 4

El resultado me arroja los seis registros pero el valor de cada variable recoje todas las opciones, como una sola cadena. Obviamente, estoy interesado en que cada signo/síntoma en mi caso sea un valor, haciendo que cada variable sea un vector o una lista para poder analizar cada signo/síntoma por separado.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso en la importación? aplicar una función para convertir cada variable multichoice (teniendo en cuenta que el estudio tiene muchas variables de ese tipo me resulta muy costoso en tiempo)

Espero que haya planteado el problema convenientemente, y agradezco por adelantado toda la ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones si entiendo bien el paciente puede tener múltiples traumas pero todos estos se están colocando en una misma columna como por ejemplo `"Flashbacks Avoidance Nightmares/Night_Terror"` y de acuerdo al screenshot del sistema proporcionado en el post corresponden a tres traumas.

Comment: Según entiendo, necesitas hacer un split de estos traumas `strsplit("Flashbacks Avoidance Nightmares/Night_Terror", "\\s+")[[1]])` [puedes intentarlo aquí](https://repl.it/repls/DistortedArtisticPackages) pero quizás podrías proveer un ejemplo de como `1 2 6 3 5 4` se corresponden con los tres traumas  `Flashbacks`, `Avoidance` y `Nightmares/Night_Terror` para ver como se tienen que agrupar.

Comment: Hola Pedro. Muy interesante pregunta. No me queda del todo claro la estructura final que buscas. ¿La idea es hacer un data.frame anidado? En ese caso cada columna sería una variable (como `sign_trauma`) y cada fila una lista (creo que no podría ser un vector) en la que cada elemento es un síntoma? En mi experiencia en estos casos de variables con categorías no excluyentes lo mejor suelen ser las dummies, para mantener la rectangularidad de los datos, usando un prefijo de variable para facilitar el manejo con `grepl` o `dplyr::select(startsWith("prefijo"))`

Comment: Aunque esto no tiene que ver con **R** mencionaste que diseñaste el formulario con **XLSForms** y por ende la estructura de la base de datos. En la parte de selección en cascada de XLSForms [Cascading Select](http://xlsform.org/en/#cascading-selects) se habla de una correspondencia **1:N** es decir un paciente y por sesión puede tener múltiples traumas con su respectivo puntaje, si puedes crear con **XLSForms** la tabla como la necesitas, te será mucho más fácil hacer luego las consultas en **R**

Comment: Claro siguiendo las buenas prácticas de [normalización de base de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)

Comment: Muchas gracias @mpaladino. Efectivamente mi estructura final tendría que ser un data frame con cada fila una observación (paciente en mi caso) y cada variable un tipo de información sobre ese paciente. El problema es cuando las variables corresponden a un grupo de manifestaciones clínicas y en la encuesta clínica se marcan como valores no excluyentes de la misma variable. Es lo que voy a intentar desarrollar: que cada variable sea una lista con los valores para cada observación.

Comment: Me parece muy interesante lo del prefijo para poder identificar cada variable (en mi caso manifestación clínica de un mismo grupo/variable) Voy a intentarlo así. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Desde la importación, lamentablemente no. Lo que si puedes es importar los datos tal como mencionas y "procesar" luego la columna `sign_trauma` para separar cada síntoma en una nueva columna. Esto con las herramientas adecuadas es sumamente sencillo, supongamos un `data.frame` ya importado como el siguiente:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7),
                 sign_trauma=factor(c('A/C/D', 'A/B', 'C/B/D', 'C/E', 'A/B/F', 'C/D/E/G', NA)))
df

  id sign_trauma
1  1       A/C/D
2  2         A/B
3  3       C/B/D
4  4         C/E
5  5       A/B/F
6  6     C/D/E/G
7  7        <NA>
```

Para hacer más sencillo, los síntomas son solo letras, puedes observar que hay mucha variabilidad de casos, alguna fila de hecho sin síntomas. Una forma de organizar esta información es convertir cada síntoma en una nueva columna, dónde `TRUE` nos indicará que existe dicho síntoma. Para realizar esto podremos hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    # Split de los síntomas en una columna por cada uno
    separate_rows(sign_trauma, sep="/") %>%
    # Creamos una nueva columna (Si existe el síntoma el valor será TRUE)
    mutate(value=TRUE) %>%
    # Deplegamos las filas con cada síntoma en una nueva columna, si el id no lo tiene será FALSE
    spread(sign_trauma, value, fill=FALSE) %>%
    # Esto es opcional, solo para verificar la columna original versus las nuevas
    left_join(df)


  id     A     B     C     D     E     F     G  <NA> sign_trauma
1  1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE       A/C/D
2  2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE         A/B
3  3 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE       C/B/D
4  4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE         C/E
5  5  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE       A/B/F
6  6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE     C/D/E/G
7  7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE        <NA>
```

Particularmente positivo que `separate_rows()` logra tratar un `factor` como `sign_trauma` sin problemas. Pero de todas formas, al leer, es conveniente usar el parámetro `stringsAsFactor = FALSE` para evitar el comportamiento automático de convertir las cadenas en factores.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio; efectivamente empiezo a pensar que la única forma posible es procesar los datos importados a través de funciones como las que amablemente sugieres. Mi problema es que he incluido en la pregunta un mero ejemplo en el que recojo unas respuestas para un determinado tipo de manifestación clínica; pero el estudio es muy extenso y como esta pregunta multi-respuesta de ejemplo tengo casi 20 más.

Comment: Por ello, tampoco he contemplado como opción la idea de importar cada una de las respuestas como una variable/columna porque haría que mi base de datos tuviera más de 300 columnas (unas 30 variables/preguntas pero con más de 10 posibles respuestas no excluyentes para cada una) Pienso que lo mejor sería que cada variable que recoge las multi respuestas fuera una lista, como amablemente sugiere @mpaladino Estoy  viendo como hacerlo de la mejor forma posible. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si tenemos el archivo con la forma

```
## prueba.csv
# id    sign_trauma
# 1 A C D
# 2 A B
# 3 C B D
# 4 C E
# 5 A B F
# 6 C D E G
# 7
```

*Tomado del ejemplo de @Patricio Moracho. Se puede aplicar también lo siguiente, si requerimos algunas métricas básicas:

Para leerlo usamos `file`

```
# con<- file("prueba.csv")
# datos <- readLines( con )
# close(con )
# datos
```

Y los datos tendrá una forma de lista

```
datos<-list( "id,sign_trauma",
               "1,A C D",
               "2,A B",
               "3,C B D",
               "4,C E",
               "5,A B F",
               "6,C D E G",
               "7,"
            )

# Aplicamos un split entre los espacios (`\\s+`) y las comas (`,`)
# de cada fila se unen con el operador or (`|`)
data <- sapply(datos,strsplit,"\\s+|," )

# eliminamos las cabeceras porque no corresponderan
# después del split
data <- data[ -1 ]

# determinamos la cantidad de columnas a partir de nuestra lista
ncol = max(sapply(data,length))

# establecemos una funcion (FUN) 
# que en cada fila le asigne el valor correspindiente de 
# data y cuando no lo encuentre asignara NA
df<-as.data.frame(
    sapply(1:ncol,function(i) lapply(data,"[",i))
)

df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  A  C  D NA
2  2  A  B NA NA
3  3  C  B  D NA
4  4  C  E NA NA
5  5  A  B  F NA
6  6  C  D  E  G
7  7 NA NA NA NA

# cuantos elementos de "A" hay
# visualizamos todo

1*(df=="A")
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  0  1  0  0 NA
[2,]  0  1  0 NA NA
[3,]  0  0  0  0 NA
[4,]  0  0  0 NA NA
[5,]  0  1  0  0 NA
[6,]  0  0  0  0  0
[7,]  0 NA NA NA NA

sum(df=="A", na.rm = TRUE)
3
```

Lo puedes ejecutar acá en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/ImperfectGleefulLinuxkernel)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Hubert. Como he desarrollado en el comentario a la amable respuesta de @patricio-moracho voy a intentar codificar algo para que cada variable multi respuesta sea una lista, porque es que tengo más de 30 valoraciones clínicas (variables) con más de 10 respuestas no excluyentes entre sí, por lo que el diseño que veo más adecuado por el momento es data.frame o un tibble con cada variable multi-respuesta como una lista. A ver s consigo hacerlo. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si esto va a ser una respuesta completa, pero al menos podría servir para orientarte en el trabajo. 
El código que sigue

- Selecciona un conjunto de columnas con cierta cadena (podría ser un prefijo o cualquier otra cosa que haga match con una expresión regular)

  - Si las columnas que te interesa convertir en lista no tienen un prefijo podrías pasar entre `[]` los números de índice. Con cuidado, no es buena idea porque cualquier movimiento de columnas (si agregas o eliminas alguna) cambia los números y tienes que actualizarlo. Da mucho trabajo, puedo dar testimonio ;)
- A cada columna selecciona la convierte en una lista de listas. En el último nivel de la lista están las respuestas como vector de la clase `character`. Cada una de esas columnas es una lista, que forma parte de una lista más abarcativa que es el `data.frame`.
- Normaliza los largos de esos vectores, para que los datos sean rectangulares. No es estrictamente necesario, pero es algún momento lo vas a necesitar. Por ejemplo, te podría ayudar a convertir cada columna en un `df` o `matrix` para tu análisis.

Va el código:

```
library(stringr) #Porque nunca me acuerdo del orden de los argumentos de las funciones base para cadenas. 
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7),
                 sign_trauma=factor(c('A/C/D', 'A/B', 'C/B/D', 'C/E', 'A/B/F', 'C/D/E/G', NA)), 
                 sign_trauma2 = factor(c("foo/bar", "bar/foo/baz", "foo/baz", "bar/baz", "foo", NA, "bar/baz")))

df[grepl("sign", names(df))] <- lapply(df[grepl("sign", names(df))], str_split,"/")

normalizar_largos <- function(x) {
  largo_max <- max(sapply(x, length))
  lapply(x, `length<-`, largo_max)}

df[grepl("sign", names(df))] <- lapply(df[grepl("sign", names(df))], normalizar_largos)

str(df)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ id          : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
$ sign_trauma :List of 7
..$ : chr  "A" "C" "D" NA
..$ : chr  "A" "B" NA NA
..$ : chr  "C" "B" "D" NA
..$ : chr  "C" "E" NA NA
..$ : chr  "A" "B" "F" NA
..$ : chr  "C" "D" "E" "G"
..$ : chr  NA NA NA NA
$ sign_trauma2:List of 7
..$ : chr  "foo" "bar" NA
..$ : chr  "bar" "foo" "baz"
..$ : chr  "foo" "baz" NA
..$ : chr  "bar" "baz" NA
..$ : chr  "foo" NA NA
..$ : chr  NA NA NA
..$ : chr  "bar" "baz" NA
```

## Observaciones

Si tomas este camino deberías estar muy familiarizado o dispuesto  a familiriarizarte con `lapply()` o (quizás mejor aún, sobre todo por `map2()`) con `purrr::`. Todo lo que hagas en cada una estas columnas "mágicas" va a tener que ser iterando sobre la lista, `dplyr::` no va a ayudar mucho para esto. Si estás trabajando en un proyecto importante al que dedicarás tiempo quizás valga la pena invertir trabajo en definir funciones para las operaciones de manipulación más frecuentes. ¿Qué funciones? Dependería del análisis que estés haciendo.

Por mi experiencia en análisis de datos con problemas similares sigo pensado que es mejor trabajar con datos rectangulares, en este caso una matriz de dummies con una columna para cada síntoma y `Sí` `No` `NA` en las filas. @Patricio Moracho te pasó código que te podría servir mucho para crear esa estructura. Se pueden usar prefijos de columna para facilitar las cosas y usar `gather()` `spread()` de `tidyr::` para ciertas operaciones, usando `group_by()` para mantener la estructura de variable original. Dependerá, sobre todo, del tipo de análisis que estés tratando de hacer. Es decir, si te interesa explorar cada variable, ver relaciones entre variables, ajustar algún tipo de modelo.

Entiendo que te preocupa el ancho de tu base de datos. No me preocuparía mucho por el uso de memoria, en listas o en columnas van a tener que estar almacenadas. Si te preocupa la carga cognitiva de tener que rastrear muchos nombres de columnas parecidos, creo que los prefijos ayudan mucho. Y, en mi opinión, la carga cognitiva de tener que rastrear todo el tiempo el nivel de la lista en el que estás trabajando es aún mayor. Es decir, quizás termines agregando a la lista de síntomas traumáticos "Counting nested `lapply()` parentheses"