# Análisis de variables multivalor en R

Tags: r

os rogaría ayuda con un problema que tengo en R en el que estoy absolutamente atascado, y ya no sé como seguir.

Estoy tratando de analizar los datos generados mediante una encuesta de satisfacción de usuarios en el que hay preguntas que admiten múltiples respuestas. La pregunta 1 admite que el usuario responda A o B o ambas(A y B) Imaginemos que la encuesta la responden tres usuarios:

Usuario 1 marca A
Usuario 2 marca B
Usuario 3 marca A y B

Cuando importo la tabla obtengo:

> tabla$usuario: chr "Usuario 1" "Usuario 2" "Usuario 3"
>
> tabla$respuesta: chr "A" "B" "A B"

Si fuera una variable unirespuesta, no tendría problemas, porque convierto la variable a factor y puedo hacer mi analisis (como por ejemplo con variables simples como si/no o masculino/femenino) pero si intento cambiar la variable respuesta a factor, tengo el problema de que considera tres "levels": "A" "B" y "A B";

> tabla$respuesta <- as.factor(tabla$respuesta)
>
> tabla$respuesta: factor w/3 levels "A" "B" "A B": 1 2 3

lo que no me sirve porque yo necesito computar el usuario tres como una observación con level "A" y level "B" simultaneamente.

Pensé en usar la función strsplit() antes de hacer la conversión  en factor y después pasar a factor con unlist():

> tabla$respuesta <- as.factor(unlist(strsplit(tabla$respuesta, " ")))

Sin embargo, esto me da un error porque divide la respuesta del usuario tres en dos observaciones diferentes, con lo que arroja un error porque no existe la observación 4.

Si no lo convierto en factor, puedo llegar a tener una lista con las respuestas, la respuesta del usuario 1 es una lista con un solo elemento (A), las del usuario 2 tiene un elemento(B) y la del usuario tres tiene dos elementos ("A" y "B") Aquí lo que pasa es que mi conocimiento de R no me da para ir más allá y, por ejemplo, graficar esta tabla, por ejemplo un gráfico de barras para ver cuantos usuarios respondieron A y cuantos B (incluidos los que respondieron ambas) Siempre he graficado con factores.

He intentado también separar las variable multivalor respuesta en columnas donde se determina logicamente TRUE o FALSE en función si el usuario ha marcado o no la casilla; y entonces podría contar los números de "TRUE" pero me lio con el graficado así con valores lógicos.

¿Se os ocurre alguna forma de hacer el analisis de datos dispuestos de esta forma?

Muchísimas gracias por adelantado, estoy absolutamente atascado con esto.

Comment: Hola Pedro, ¿en que difiere esta pregunta de esta otra: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239416/dividir-variable-factor-en-r? Si quieres una opinión, solo puede hacerlo como comentario, creo que la todo va a depender de cual es el análisis posterior que hagas. Básicamente creo que hay dos formas cómodas de manejar esto, siempre, pensando en un `dataframe`: 1) Cada fila es un usuario, pregunta y tienes n columnas para cada opción posible con valores Verdadero/falso. 2) Una fila por usuario, pregunta, opción elegida, aquí claro tendrías más de una fila por pregunta.

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias de nuevo por atender mis preguntas. Lamento la duplicación pero intenté responder mi propia pregunta y la página me recomendaba mejor editar la pregunta origina y me ha parecido más complejo. Lamento mucho haber duplicado la pregunta, lo siento. Al final, ayudado por vosotros, efectivamente he pensado que lo más fácil en lo de tener n columnas (el problema es que se ma va la tabla a 351 columnas!!!) y entonces graficar los resultados me parece muy muy complicado (al menos yo no sé)

Comment: Intentaba, aunque duplicando lamentablemente la pregunta, dar un ejemplo , más simple, para ver si existe una forma de tratar de otra forma variables multi valor. Muchisimas gracias como siempre.

Comment: Me puedes ayudar en cómo graficar valores lógicos?...como puedo hacer un gráfico para computar las respuestas si estan en n columnas con valores true o false?

Comment: ¿Que tipo de gráfico estas intentando realizar? en función de esto tal vez te convenga una forma u otra.

Comment: Pues mira, las preguntas son acerca de síntomas de pacientes. Tengo mil pacientes con preguntas en las que el personal clínico marca todos los signos  que identifican en los pacientes. Si la pregunta tiene trece posible manifestaciones clínicas, por ejemplo, para cada pregunta tendré después 13 columnas para cada signo con 1000 valores (verdadero o falso) Es por esto que ya nada más que seleccionar las columnas a incluir en el análisis y en los gráficos me resulta ya complejo.

Comment: Un gráfico básico que necesitaría es la distribución de frecuencias de signos entre los pacientes y posibles relaciones: ¿existe relación entre la frecuencia del signo A y del signo B? ¿existe relación entre el signo A y el domicilio del paciente? ¿relación entre signos y edad? Con variables univalor, consideradas como factor, puedo manejarme, pero con una tabla tan grande con valores lógicos, no sé como seguir. Estoy completamente atascado.

Comment: entiende que no hablo de relaciones formalmente estadistica, para las que tendría que crear modelos. Por el momento solo quiero hacer analisis exploratorio gráfico para seleccionar las posibles relaciones que quiero seguir investigando. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesariamente una distribución de los datos que sea útil para un modelado lo sea también para llevarlos a una gráfica. Voy a tratar de generalizar una respuesta. En primer lugar partamos de un ejemplo como el que has mencionado:

```
set.seed(2019)
df <- data.frame(usuario = sample(c("U1","U2","U3", "U4", "U5"), 50, replace=TRUE),
                 pregunta = sample(c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"), 50, replace=TRUE),
                 respuesta = sample(c("A","B","A B", "C", "B C", "A B C", "A C", "D", "B D"), 50, replace=TRUE)
)
head(df)

  usuario pregunta respuesta
1      U4       P2       B C
2      U4       P1         D
3      U2       P1         C
4      U4       P2         D
5      U1       P3         C
6      U1       P2     A B C
```

Son 4 preguntas con 5 posibles y combinables respuestas y 5 usuarios. Las respuestas combinadas se reciben en una cadena separada por espacio.

Si nos adherimos a los principios de [**Tidy Data**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data), deberíamos hablar que cada observación debiera ser una fila y cada variable una columna. Ciertamente, pareciera que aquí la observación es la encuesta, y las variables debieran ser entonces cada pregunta/respuesta. Esta organización no necesariamente es cómoda para graficar los datos. Mucho más cómodo para esto último es tener una apertura completa, es decir abierto por usuario, pregunta y respuesta. Por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    # Split de las respuestas en nuevas filas
    separate_rows(respuesta, sep=" ")  %>% 
    # Atención: unique() solo sirve por que generamoslos datos al azar 
    # lo cual hace que no sean consistentes y podamos tener eventualmente
    # respuestas repetidas por preguntas
    unique() %>% 
    arrange(pregunta, usuario) -> final

head(final)

  usuario pregunta respuesta
1      U1       P1         B
2      U1       P1         A
3      U2       P1         C
4      U3       P1         B
5      U3       P1         D
6      U4       P1         D
```

Con esto hemos "abierto" las respuesta múltiples en `n` filas. Ahora hacer un gráfico de barras para evaluar la distribución de las respuestas por cada pregunta con `ggplot` es muy sencillo:

```
ggplot(final, aes(x=respuesta)) +
    geom_bar() +
    facet_wrap(~pregunta)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, si necesitamos hacer otro tipo de análisis, un modelado, clustering, etc. Sin duda, conviene una organización mas consistente con los principios de [**Tidy Data**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data). Lo bueno que podemos aprovechar el `data.frame` anterior (`final`) y reorganizarlo a nuestro gusto:

```
final %>% 
    # Unifico PREGUNTAS + RESPUESTAS
    unite(PR, pregunta, respuesta, sep=".") %>%
    # Creo una nueva columna value
    mutate(value=TRUE) %>%
    # Deplegamos las filas con cada opcion en una nueva columna
    spread(PR, value, fill=FALSE) -> final

final

  usuario  P1.A  P1.B  P1.C  P1.D  P2.A P2.B  P2.C  P2.D  P3.A  P3.B P3.C  P3.D  P4.A  P4.B  P4.C  P4.D
1      U1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
2      U2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3      U3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4      U4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
5      U5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Y aquí vemos, que cada fila se corresponde efectivamente a una observación encuesta y cada variable representa una pregunta/respuesta. Esto seguramente puede asustar un poco, si hablamos de 1000 usuarios, suponiendo (no lo has mencionado) que tienes 20 preguntas con un máximo de 13 posibles opciones, estamos hablando de un `data.frame` de 100 filas y 20 x 13 = 260 columnas. No es un numero de columnas para preocuparse, el límite de estas, según entiendo es de 2^31 - 1. La ventaja de esta organización, es que se adapta mejor a parte del análisis que has mencionado. Por ejemplo, ¿que correlación existe entre la respuesta A de la pregunta 1 y la B de la pregunta 3?

```
cor(final[,c("P1.A","P3.B")])
```

¿Y plantear un modelo lineal?

```
lm(P1.A ~ P3.B, final)
```

¿Y si quisiéramos agrupar los usuarios en 2 grupos en función a sus respuestas?

```
hc <- hclust(dist(final[, -1]), method = "complete")
cutree(hc, k=2)
```

Como puedes ver, "abiertos" los datos de esta forma, puede ser mucho más cómodo para ciertas acciones posteriores que debas tomar.

Comment: Estimado Patricio, ante todo acepta mis más sinceras disculpas por tardar tanto en contestarte, pero precisamente he estado viajando y muy ocupado con ela análisis al que me refería en la pregunta, y hasta ahora no he tenido un rato para escribir esto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido perfectamente el tipo de análisis que me has sugerido y he podido hacer con tu magnífica ayuda lo que pretendía y me pedías. Muchas gracias, tu respuesta ha sido de una grandísima ayuda. Un afectuoso saludo.